# Are there any other uses for a star algorithm other than just in pathfinding field?

Tags: c, algorithm

The goal for my code is to find the least number of nodes to forward a message to so that the maximum number of nodes (if not all) receive the message. Only the nodes directly connected to the user with the message will be able to view the message. So far i could only get the setting up of the network, so if anyone could help me with the algorithm and finding part it would be of a great help.(also would help if it was in c).

P.S.
(Excuse for the mistakes in language or anything, kinda new all this)

what i have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node
{
    int vertex;
    struct node* next;
};

int total = 0, best = 0;

void main()
{
    struct node* Adj[80];
    int i, no_of_nodes;
    printf("\nEnter the number of total friends in a social network :");
    scanf("%d", &no_of_nodes);
    for (i = 0; i < no_of_nodes; i++)
    {
        Adj[i] = NULL;
    }
    readG(Adj, no_of_nodes);
    printf("\n \n");
    printf("\n The social network is: ");
    displayG(Adj, no_of_nodes);
}

void readG(struct node* Adj[], int no_of_nodes)
{
    struct node *new_node, *last;
    int i, j, n, val;
    total = total + no_of_nodes;
    for (i = 0; i < no_of_nodes; i++)
    {
        last = NULL;
        printf("\nEnter the number of friends of %d : ", i);
        scanf("%d", &n);
        total += n;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("\nEnter the friend of %d of %d :", j, i);
            scanf("%d", &val);
            new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            new_node->vertex = val;
            new_node->next = NULL;
            if (Adj[i] == NULL)
            {
                Adj[i] = new_node;
            }
            else
            {
                last->next = new_node;
            }
            last = new_node;
        }
    }
}

void displayG(struct node* Adj[], int no_of_nodes)
{
    struct node* ptr;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < no_of_nodes; i++)
    {
        ptr = Adj[i];
        printf("\n The friends of %d are : ", i);
        while (ptr != NULL)
        {
            printf("\t%d", ptr->vertex);
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like _...so if anyone could help me with the algorithm and finding part..._ is the main part of the problem.  What have you tried so far?  Try Googling _fewest nodes search alogrithm in C_.

Comment: @ryyker:Yes that's the important part and i couldn't come up with anything. Also i tried googling fewest nodes search algorithm but i couldn't get anything helpful